# mPDF 5.3 - image displays as a broken [x] when base64

Tags: php, html, image, apache2, mpdf

I have strange problem when generating pdf with image.

It works great when I set image like this:

```
 <td><img src='1.png'></td>
```

But when I set the same image like this:

```
<td><img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAC8SURBVGhD7ZGxEcIwEASVUQUluAhiYipx4hLcBA1QCxWQ0QAJBdinVDoC2TPoHm5nNvnodj4ZQV47PEMZlh0+4AFKwAa2OEEJ2LgW3/AIu8PGtXqD3WHDtniCXWGjtviE+TO9pKMiSo8RpceIVocrnMXNG8vd1WGA6uSN5e7q4JAv4hA1HKKGQ9RwiBoOUcMhajhEDYeo4RA1HKKGQ9RwiBr/FTLCi7h5Y7m7OkSVHiNKjxFN9x/RGPORlFYYKPr/Go+FXQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='></td>
```

When generating pdf, image displays as a broken **[x]**.

Cheking apache2 error log I founded:

```
[Mon Oct 01 10:00:23 2018] [error] [client x] File does not exist: /opt/data/htdocs/test/cases/data:image
```

But have no idea why is this error, because image file is encoded in base64 correctly.

I am using mPDF 5.3 and PHP 5.3

Code to generate PDF with image file:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('lt','A4','','',5,5,10,5,1,1);
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($css, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html2);
$mpdf->Output($pdf_filename, $pdf_destination);
```

Comment: Can you try a newer version? This HTML code works for me in mPDF 7.1

Comment: what is your PHP version?

Comment: 7.2. You should be able to run mPDF 7.1 with PHP 5.6. PHP 5.3 is way too old and insecure, consider upgrading.